# chrome headless with no ssl error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I want to use chrome headless browser for my FT suite. I don't have ssl certificates on my local machine.

Is there a way to ignore SSL errors. In phantom I just pass following commands: `--web-security=no --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=yes` and it works. But phantom is not supporting `ES6` so want to try chrome.

Comment: Did you found an answer already? Having exactly the same problem..

Comment: No, I had to make self-sign certificate trusted and then chrome headless worked.